# Distinguish three fraction forms (feature stronger than Hold)

Tags: front-end, evaluation, output-formatting, notebooks, expression-manipulation

This question can not be typed easily, using mathematica stackexchange interface.

So here is a GIF file :

[image]

My question is : **Can we construct a function `f` whose output is**

```
f /@ {7/3, 7/3, 7/3} (* all symbols become slash symbols after copy and paste *)

{"Slash form", "MiddleBar form", "Divide form"}
```

?

[image]

For this (=the existence of such `f`) to be possible, there must be something stronger than built in `Hold`.

Comment: I think the question can be boiled down to "Why does `Hold[7÷3]` evaluate to `Hold[7/3]`? When does the conversion happen?" Interesting question. (+1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no `f` that could do this** by itself because those forms are taken care of during parsing.

So by the time any evaluation rules associated with `f` take an effect there will be no trace of `\[Divide]` and only `\` (or rather `Times` and `Power`).

Your input which is sent for evaluation is:

```
RowBox[{"{", 
  RowBox[{RowBox[{"7", "/", "3"}], ",", 
  FractionBox["7", "3"], ",", 
  RowBox[{"7", "\[Divide]", "3"}]}], 
"}"}]
```

but we can exercise on a simpler string:

```
FullForm @ MakeExpression["f[7\[Divide]3]", StandardForm ]
```

> `HoldComplete[f[Times[7, Power[3, -1]]]]`

You can intercept parsing but that's a modification to an 'environment' rather than evaluation alone so you'd need to provide a specific use case in order to get a suited solution.

Here is one example of such enhancement:

```
{7/3, 7/3, 7/3} (* original cell with 2D typesetting *)
```

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{MakeExpression}
, MakeExpression[RowBox[{n_, "/", d_}], fmt_] := HoldComplete["Slash form"]
; MakeExpression[RowBox[{n_, "\[Divide]", d_}], fmt_] := HoldComplete["Divide form"]
; MakeExpression[FractionBox[n_, d_], fmt_] := HoldComplete["MiddleBar form"]

; ToExpression @ NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]][[1, 1]]
]
```

> `{"Slash form", "MiddleBar form", "Divide form"}`

Comment: I was preparing something to comment, but somehow I ran out of such things. Thank you for answering this difficult question!